# How do I compare a program specified as a free monad against a description of expected instructions?

Tags: haskell, types, interpreter, free-monad

So I'm trying to do something that's kind of novel (I think), but I'm not
experienced enough with Haskell type-level programming to work it out myself.

I've got a free monad describing some effects to perform (an AST, if that's the
way you roll), and I want to interpret it against some description of the
effects that are expected.

Here's my code so far::

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor, FlexibleInstances, GADTs, FlexibleContexts #-}
import Control.Monad.Free -- from package 'free'

data DSL next
    = Prompt String (String -> next)
    | Display String next
    deriving (Show, Functor)

prompt p = liftF (Prompt p id)
display o = liftF (Display o ())

-- |Just to make sure my stuff works interactively
runIO :: (Free DSL a) -> IO a
runIO (Free (Prompt p cont)) = do
    putStr p
    line <- getLine
    runIO (cont line)
runIO (Free (Display o cont)) = do putStrLn o; runIO cont
runIO (Pure x) = return x
```

That's the "core" code. Here's an example program:

```
greet :: (Free DSL ())
greet = do
    name <- prompt "Enter your name: "
    let greeting = "Why hello there, " ++ name ++ "."
    display greeting
    friendName <- prompt "And what is your friend's name? "
    display ("It's good to meet you too, " ++ friendName ++ ".")
```

To test this program, I want to use a function `runTest :: Free DSL a -> _ -> Maybe a`, which should take a program and some specification of "expected effects" vaguely like this:

```
expect = (
    (Prompt' "Enter your name:", "radix"),
    (Display' "Why hello there, radix.", ()),
    (Prompt' "And what is your friend's name?", "Bob"),
    (Display' "It's good to meet you too, Bob.", ()))
```

and interpret the program by matching each effect that it performs against the next item in the `expect` list. Then the associated value (the second item in each pair) should be returned as the result of that effect to the program. If all the effects match, the final result of the program should be returned as a `Just`. If something doesn't match, `Nothing` should be returned (later I'll expand this so that it returns an informative error message).

Of course this `expect` tuple is useless, since its type is a big giant thing that I can't write a generic `runTest` function over. The main problem I'm having is how I should represent this sequence of expected intents in a way that I can write a function that works with any sequence against any program `Free DSL a`.

1. I'm vaguely aware of various advanced type-level features in Haskell, but I'm not yet experienced to know which things I should try to use.
2. Should I be using an HList or something for my `expected` sequence?

Any hints for things to look into are greatly appreciated.

Comment: It seems like `expect` should be a function inside a type class, and the various `Prompt`, `Display`, etc, correspond to different type class instances. But it isn't exactly a good thing to have one identifier be some magic function that does everything, depending on the context - it will make readers of your code very confused.

Comment: 1. you can ignore the `expect` stuff, it's not the main part of my question 2. I'm not sure why `expect` would be in a typeclass, as I'm not sure what multiple instances it would have. 3. I actually do have `prompt` and `display` in a typeclass, but it's for reasons unrelated to this question 4. `expect` is specifically in the context of testing code -- since it's specifically a way to write test assertions, I don't think it will be unclear.

Comment: update: I'm messing around with the `operational` package which at least is allowing me to describe my data types in a nice way, and I'm pretty happy about that... it let me basically unify my `Intent` and `DSL` data types. I think I might be getting closer.

Comment: You might be interested in [this post](http://dlaing.org/cofun/posts/free_and_cofree.html), it defines a DSL and an interpreter datatype and pairs these datatypes. I get the impression your main problem is that the second element in your expect tuples is of variable type - if you get around this by wrapping the expected effects in a new datatype (i.e. `data ExpEffect = StrEffect ... | VoidEffect ...`) I think you can use any kind of list for holding these values as your language is linear.

Comment: Thanks for the link, Sam. Actually, my problem isn't just the second value in each tuple -- the first one has a varying type as well (either `Intent String` or `Intent ()`, depending on the constructor used). I'll check out that article to see if I can learn anything.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A test for a program `Free f a` is just an interpreter for the program `Free f a -> r` producing some result `r`

What you are looking for is an easy way to build interpreters for the program that assert that the outcome of the program is what you expected. Each step of the interpreter will either unwrap a `Free f` instruction from the program or describe some error. They'll have the type

```
Free DSL a -> Either String (Free DSL a)
|                    |       ^ the remaining program after this step
|                    ^ a descriptive error
^ the remaining program before this step
```

We'll make a test for each of the constructors in the `DSL`. `prompt'` expects a `Prompt` with a specific value and provides the response value to the function to find what's next.

```
prompt' :: String -> String -> Free DSL a -> Either String (Free DSL a)
prompt' expected response f =
    case f of
        Free (Prompt p cont) | p == expected -> return (cont response)
        otherwise                            -> Left $ "Expected (Prompt " ++ show expected ++ " ...) but got " ++ abbreviate f

abbreviate :: Free DSL a -> String
abbreviate (Free (Prompt  p _)) = "(Free (Prompt "  ++ show p ++ " ...))"
abbreviate (Free (Display p _)) = "(Free (Display " ++ show p ++ " ...))"
abbreviate (Pure _)             = "(Pure ...)"
```

`display'` expects a `Display` with a specific value.

```
display' :: String -> Free DSL a -> Either String (Free DSL a)
display' expected f =
    case f of
        Free (Display p next) | p == expected -> return next
        otherwise                             -> Left $ "Expected (Display " ++ show expected ++ " ...) but got " ++ abbreviate f
```

`pure'` expects a `Pure` with a specific value

```
pure' :: (Eq a, Show a) => a -> Free DSL a -> Either String ()
pure' expected f = 
    case f of
        Pure a | a == expected -> return ()
        otherwise              -> Left $ "Expected " ++ abbreviate' (Pure expected) ++ " but got " ++ abbreviate' f

abbreviate' :: Show a => Free DSL a -> String
abbreviate' (Pure a) = "(Pure " ++ showsPrec 10 a ")"
abbreviate' f        = abbreviate f
```

With `prompt'` and `display'` we can easily build an interpreter in the style of `expect`.

```
expect :: Free DSL a -> Either String (Free DSL a)
expect f = return f >>=
           prompt' "Enter your name:" "radix" >>=
           display' "Why hello there, radix." >>=
           prompt' "And what is your friend's name?" "Bob" >>=
           display' "It's good to meet you too, Bob."
```

Running this test

```
main = either putStrLn (putStrLn . const "Passed") $ expect greet
```

Results in a failure

```
Expected (Prompt "Enter your name:" ...) but got (Free (Prompt "Enter your name: " ...))
```

Once we change the test to expect spaces at the end of the prompts

```
expect :: Free DSL a -> Either String (Free DSL a)
expect f = return f >>=
           prompt' "Enter your name: " "radix" >>=
           display' "Why hello there, radix." >>=
           prompt' "And what is your friend's name? " "Bob" >>=
           display' "It's good to meet you too, Bob."
```

Running it results in

```
Passed
```

Comment: I'm working through reading/understanding this answer, but for onlookers who may be confused: I have changed my question to use Control.Monad.Operational `MyEffect a`, but previously it was using a plain free monad from Control.Monad.Free, `Free DSL a`, so that's why Cirdec's answer is talking about `Free DSL a`.

Comment: I'm so excited about your answer, Cirdec! I think I get it -- I was trying to shoehorn my "expect" sequence into a plain data structure when I really should have made it a "program"! So, basically, `expect` is an ad-hoc test interpreter for a specific program. I'm going to try adapting this to my Operational-based program now.

Comment: I think you forgot a call to `pure' "blacrg"` in your `expect` definition at the end?

Comment: I left it off since it wasn't part of your `expect` definition. If you add it, the type of `expect` changes to `expect :: Free DSL String -> Either String ()`.

Comment: Sorry, I realized that I didn't have that return statement in the original version of the question.

Comment: Cirdec - I've got your solution basically working against my Operational-based monad. I'm currently wroking on polishing it up to include the error messages etc. To make this Q/A more sensible, would you prefer that I revert the question to have the Free DSL version, or do you want to update your answer with the Operational-based code I'm working on? I can post a Gist shortly with the working code and you can copy whatever bits you want into your answer.

Comment: Here's the gist of the updated solution: https://gist.github.com/radix/44bbeb2e472f119b1c69 I'll let you decide if you want to copy it into your answer. If you don't want to update your answer, let me know and I'll revert the question to the Free DSL version. :)

Comment: You can always add your own `Operational` answer.

Comment: I know, but I would rather give you the credit for accepted answer, since it was all your work :)

Comment: There's one potential advantage to a `Free` solution: with that, you can share a lot of code by using automatically generated `Prism`s from the `lens` library, which might help when you get more constructors (With a few other changes to give the constructors more similar structure, I managed to write an `ex` function such that `prompt' = ex _Prompt` and ``display' = ex _Display `flip` ()``). With a GADT solution like `operational`, this fails because of existential types.

Comment: If you'd like to use this (or edit it into the answer), here it is: ``ex :: (Show e, Eq e) => Prism' (DSL (Free DSL a)) (e, r -> Free DSL a) -> e -> r -> Free DSL a -> Either String (Free DSL a);
ex prism expected response f =
    case preview (_Free.prism) f of
        Just (p, cont) | p == expected -> return (cont response);
        otherwise ->
            Left $ "Expected (" ++ show (review prism (expected, undefined)) ++ ") but got " ++ abbreviate f``

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen That's a great idea, but without some typeclass machinery it won't generalize to constructors like `Repeat Int String next` and even with typeclass machinery probably can't handle constructors like `Fork next next` (neither can the current answer).

Comment: Well I imagined the constructors needed to be tweaked a bit for the structure of the prisms to match; I already had to tweak `Display` to include the `()` result argument. Perhaps you can get enough flexibility with something like `Constructor EffectData (ResultFunctor next)`, where you have a typeclass for each necessary `ResultFunctor`? the `(->) r` instance would behave as the ones already given, while `Fork` could get something like `data Pair a = Pair a a`. Presumably this would only be worth it if there are much fewer functors than constructors.

Comment: Okay, so I reverted the question to the Free DSL form and marked your answer as accepted. Thanks very much for the help, Cirdec!